# Complete list of nuclear fusion reactions

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

Could anyone suggest good source of all fusion reactions and their cross section vs energy graphs, including ones which were ruled out for nuclear fusion reactors (i.e. including endothermic and reactions with only 1 product)?

Comment: You can immediately restrict yourself to the three isotopes of Hydrogen and Lithium, everything else is too Coulombically supressed.

Comment: @RonMaimon How about B11-p near 150keV? ;-)

Comment: It's not as complete as the references given by Warrick, but there is a quick overview in the 7th slide of [this presentation by Todd Rider](http://www.longwood.edu/assets/chemphys/FusionRoute.pdf).

Comment: @mmc Your link is dead.

Comment: @Calmarius You can still retrieve the PDF [using Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20100601223744/http://www.longwood.edu/assets/chemphys/FusionRoute.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the Exfor database this is the easiest reference:

In the reaction, if you want a reaction with proton, chose p,* to select all of them
In the Quantity, I recommend to use CS,* if not no reaction will appear
After select the target in the next page, select all reations you want and then select also Quickplot and at next page, nice plot will appear like the following of boron11 + P

[Exfor database](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/exfor/exfor.htm)

[image: B11+P reaction]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but the most widely used reference for many nuclear reaction rates in stars in [Caughlan & Fowler (1988)](http://esoads.eso.org/abs/1988ADNDT..40..283C). It's not so much a paper as an enormous reference for many reactions. I've just discovered that it isn't open access yet and I'm not sure what can be done about that...

Some reaction rates have subsequently been updated and been given corrections for various effects that modify the rates inside stars. If you want a full description, you can pick up a recent stellar evolution code paper. e.g. have a look at Sections 4.4 and 4.5 of the [code paper](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011ApJS..192....3P) for [MESA](http://mesa.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 4):

You can find data of all (!?) current nuclear reaction experiments in the [evaluated nuclear reaction databases (ENDF)](https://www-nds.iaea.org/nrdc/about/about-endf.html)[*]. Bibliographic information can be found in the [experimental nuclear reaction database (EXFOR)](https://www-nds.iaea.org/nrdc/about/about-exfor.html). The databases are maintained by the cooperation of nuclear data centres worldwide in the ["International Network of Nuclear Reaction Data Centres (NRDC)"](https://www-nds.iaea.org/nrdc/).

Graphs can be easily created e.g. with [JANIS (Java-based Nuclear Data Information System)](http://www.oecd-nea.org/janis/). As an example: [n-induced cross section of H-1](http://www.oecd-nea.org/janisweb/book/neutrons/pg1/renderer/76)

[*] Not to be confused with the "Evaluated Nuclear Data File" which is one of the five databases in the ENDF.